# External mechanic inspection on CPO car?

Tags: inspection, car, used

I am about to buy a used Certified Pre-Owned(CPO) car. I have read that external mechanic inspection is recommended when buying used cars but does that hold true for CPO cars too? Would it be wise to get the inspection done?

Car I am looking at is Infiniti G37 2010 convertible.

Comment: Did anyone else read that as "Chief Petty Officer"?  Very confusing....  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on who you're buying it from and who inspected it.  Wikipedia [sums it up pretty well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_Pre-Owned).

- The factory basically makes it refurbished but the price is generally higher.
- The dealer might certify the car themselves which means it's up to them how thorough they are.
- An independent agency might be used that could be less biased but still set their own standards.

They all generally come with warranties that you can't get on a used car, which affords some peace of mind.  A second opinion from a mechanic would still help you know what you're getting into and if it's what you want.